# google maps api v2 show blank

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I developed a program that use google map api v2. First, I have been working on my pc and every thing have been ok. I moved codes to my laptop and now google maps show blank map.

I can't find out why? Is this belong to api hash key?

Answer (score 0):

You have a differen debug keystore, then its the hash key. You need to do a new one.

Comment: Thanks @Luser_k, Then how can it developed by a team? I mean 2 or more persons with no problem?

Comment: You all need the same debug, you could share it.

Comment: Could you guide me how?